# Should I level up other my newly discovered Pets?

Tags: pets-live

I'm playing [Pets Live](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/pets-live/id327013340?mt=8) and I often discover new Pets

**But is there any advantage to upgrading these** or should I just focus on my main four Pets (Water, Earth, Air & Fire) and keep those maxed out?

[image] [image]

Comment: Downloaded and trying it :)

Comment: It's the colorful images isn't it @Juan? And thanks for adding the link, I wanted to do it, but forgot about it!

Comment: Absoluteley, I wouldn't have bothered if it wasn't for the screenshots...

Comment: Well @Juan, I guess you didn't find the answer either? ;-)

Comment: :o) -- I stopped playing, I have too many addictions already

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only your 4 strongest monsters are used in combat, so it's only beneficial to maintain 4 pets.

Of course, there are better pets to be unlocked than the ones you start out unlocking. The best pets are unlocked around level 85, and the ones you use will depend on whether you want to be an attacker or defender.

For more information: [see this guide](http://forums.storm8.com/showthread.php?t=19583)